# OpenMPI how to perform MPI_Allreduce with respect to long long array

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I want to use the `MPI_Allreduce` on a very long array as the following demo.

```
long long n = 1 << 10;
double* array = new double[n];
memset(array, 1234.5678, n * sizeof(double));
MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, array, n, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

However, I have checked the official documentation and the details about the API as the following. We see that we can only use the integer to specify the total number of elements in the send buffer. What if I want to perform this API on a very long array? Do I have to split my array into many small parts and then do this collective operation?

```
int MPI_Allreduce(const void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count,
                  MPI_Datatype datatype, MPI_Op op, MPI_Comm comm)
```

Comment: That is one option. An other one is to use a derived datatype: if your array has 16G elements, you can `MPI_Type_contiguous(1024*1024, ...)` and use `count=16*1024`. FWIW future version of the MPI standard might support very large number of elements, meanwhile you can also have a look at BigMPI.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you. I think the way to derive my own datatype should be better than sending small arrays for multiple times, which might cause a lot of overhead.

Comment: As long as `count` is not a prime number, this is the way to go!

Comment: There was a discussion on the MPI forum about `long` counts and the outcome was that long counts are not needed. The rationale is that one can use derived datatypes and that sending really long messages takes so much time that the overhead from creating the derived datatypes, even if one does so for each individual message, will be negligible given the speed of most network interconnects.

Comment: Large count support is a gating feature for MPI 4.0.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet BigMPI handles primes although it isn’t guaranteed go work in a heterogeneous environment.